# Swift deal cards to players from set array of "cards"

Tags: arrays, function, swift, declaration, swift-playground

I have an array called shuffledDeck that holds 52 Int numbers shuffled I want to deal to each player individually

```
func dealCards1(){
    for i in 0...25{
        comp1PlayDeck += shuffledDeck[i]
    }
}
```

Not quite sure what I should return I am doing this to learn not for anything important
just wondering what I should do for the function declaration for exmp

```
func dealCards1(Int: Array) -> Int: Array{}
```

Im not sure how to return the array any help would be appreciated thank you! :D
here is the full code so far

```
import Foundation

let comp1 = 1
let comp2 = 2

var dealDeck =     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52]
var shuffledDeck: [Int]

var comp1PlayDeck = [Int]()
var comp2PlayDeck: [Int]

var comp1WinDeck: [Int]
var comp2WinDeck: [Int]

var comp1CurrCard: Int
var comp2CurrCard: Int



//functions
    //shuffles cards from dealDeck returns to shuffledDeck
func shuffle<T>(var list: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    for i in 0..<list.count {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(list.count - i))) + i
        list.insert(list.removeAtIndex(j), atIndex: i)
    }
    return list
}
//shuffle deck
 shuffledDeck = shuffle(dealDeck)

for num in shuffledDeck {
    println(num)
}
//deals to player one
func dealCards1() -> [Int] {
    for i in 0...25{
        comp1PlayDeck += shuffledDeck[i]
    }
    return comp1PlayDeck
}
//deals to player two
func dealCards2(){

}
comp1PlayDeck = dealCards1()
```

Comment: thanks connor was just doing that xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how you can return the dealt comp1PlayDeck from the function? If so just have the function return an Int array and return comp1PlayDeck at the end of the function.

```
var comp1PlayDeck = [Int]()
func dealCards1() -> [Int] { 
    for i in 0...25{            
        comp1PlayDeck += shuffledDeck[i]
    }
    return comp1PlayDeck
}
```

Comment: ok yes that is what I was looking for however I am getting an error now stating note: variable defined here

Comment: you have to declare the array in the function. I added a line

Comment: Ok I'll try that after I eat lunch, now I should just be able to use that through out the rest of my code. Essentially I am building the card game war

Comment: ok that works now I need to be able to use that outside of that function to compare comp1 player cards to comp2 player cards

Comment: So I took that out of the function so as to use it elsewhere `comp1PlayDeck += shuffledDeck[i]` isn't passing its elements to comp1PlayDeck

Comment: I think it would help if you show more code. It may be worth a new question

Comment: I will just append it to the OP as it does apply to it

Comment: if you want the function to modify a property on the class add the mutating keyword

Comment: upon appending `mutating` to `func` I get the error 'mutating' is only valid on methods

Comment: instead of modifying the array in the function, use it as is and set your array to the result of the function

Comment: `var comp1PlayDeck = dealCards1()`

Comment: so in that case i should return `shuffledDeck[i]`?

Comment: no because that is just a single int. You still want it to return a whole array

Comment: you want comp1PlayDeck to be an array of Int right? Then return an array of Int like it currently does

Comment: yes comp1PlayDeck is already defined at the beginning of the code however. it is already of type Int array. what is the difference between declaring it like `var varname: [Int]` and `var varname = [Int]()`